# Python - List comprehension - if statement without else possible?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Title is obviously confusing. Example:

```
>>>a = [b if len(b) != 0 else 'lambda']
```

I want to create this variable only if the statement is met. I don't want it to even exist otherwise. So how come

```
>>>a = [b if len(b) != 0]
```

gives a `SyntaxError`? Is there a way I can make this variable only exist if a statement is met in just 1 line?

Comment: List comprehensions create lists, by definition. What you want is: a = b if len(b) else 'lambda'

Comment: Just use a standard if statement outside the list comprehension like this: "if len(b) != 0: a = b"

Comment: pythonic inline condition has the following syntax `if len(b) != 0: a=[b]`

Comment: what do you want to achieve precisely? list comprehension syntax is quite clear: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions 
what is 'b'?

Comment: `b` is a single digit number. `a` is to equate to that number given that `b` is not `0`.

Comment: That's not a list comprehension.

Comment: if b is a single digit number then len(b) doesn't make sense. Instead of doing random stuff better read a python tutorial to get the basics right first.

Comment: @PYPL you've fixed it. Thought I had to define the variable first and then use it in another line doing it outside a list comprehension...

Comment: That's just a list containing a single conditional expression. List comprehensions, by definition, contain the keyword `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a list comprehension:

```
if b: a = b
```

Comment: Where's the 'lambda' string value?

Comment: he wants to create this variable only if the statement is met. he doesn't want it to even exist otherwise, read the title

Comment: @Laefica Aha so you want it in one line, look at the edited answer